# awk split var twice

Tags: awk, split

I would like to split a var twice with awk, this is what i have got so far.

```
awk -v p=1,3,8,25-27,4-16 '{split(p,t,",");for (i in t) if(t[i] ~ /-/) split(t[i],t1,"-") {print "-dFirstPage=" t1[1] ,"-dFirstPage=" t1[2]} ELSE {print "-dFirstPage=" t[i] ,"-dFirstPage=" t[i]}}' >outfile
```

output shall be

```
-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1
-dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=3
-dFirstPage=8 -dLastPage=8
-dFirstPage=25 -dLastPage=27
-dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is: **for, echo, if**

Many times faster if you have to do it thousands of times

```
vars=1,3,8,25-27,4-16
f='-dfirstpage='
l='-dlastpage='

for pages in ${vars//,/ }; do
   if [[ -n ${pages//[[:digit:]]/} ]]; then
      echo "${f}${pages%%-*} ${l}${pages##*-}"
   else
      echo "${f}${pages} ${l}${pages}"
   fi
done
```

Output

```
-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1
-dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=3
-dFirstPage=8 -dLastPage=8
-dFirstPage=25 -dLastPage=27
-dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=16
```

Answer (score 1):

You where very close, (but I'm not sure this solution will really meet your ultimate requirements).

```
 awk -v p=1,3,8,25-27,4-16 '
 END{
        split(p,t,",");
  for (i in t) {
    if(t[i] ~ /-/) {
        split(t[i],t1,"-");
      print "-dFirstPage=" t1[1] ,"-dFirstPage=" t1[2]
    }
    else {
      print "-dFirstPage=" t[i] ,"-dFirstPage=" t[i]
    }
  }
}' /dev/null > outfile
```

**Revised for windows and more general solution**

```
 echo "1,3,8,25-27,4-16" \
 | awk '
 {
   split($0,t,",");
   for (i in t) {
     if(t[i] ~ /-/) {
        split(t[i],t1,"-");
        print "-dFirstPage=" t1[1] ,"-dFirstPage=" t1[2]
     }
     else {
       print "-dFirstPage=" t[i] ,"-dFirstPage=" t[i]
     }
   }
 }' > outfile
```

Feel free to edit your question if this requires clarification.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason the script is on an invinite loop. I use gawk on windows and need to force the script to exit. When the script ended forcefully the output though is correct. Any suggestion?

Comment: Ack!, Windows doesn't have printf. See revised revision;-) .good luck.

Comment: Are you using a unix-like environment on Windows, like cygwin or Mingw (or others), or the cmd.exe from windows to execute this? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=1,3,8,25-27,4-16

for pages in `echo $vars | tr ',' '\n'`; do
    if [[ -n $( echo $pages | grep --only-matching "-" ) ]]; then
        firstPage=`echo ${pages%%-*}`
        lastPage=`echo ${pages##*-}`
    else
        firstPage=$pages
        lastPage=$pages
    fi
    echo "-dFirstPage=${firstPage} -dLastPage=${lastPage}"
done
```

Output:

```
-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1
-dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=3
-dFirstPage=8 -dLastPage=8
-dFirstPage=25 -dLastPage=27
-dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=16
```

---

Apply some @shellter's advices:

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=1,3,8,25-27,4-16
for pages in `echo $vars | tr ',' '\n'`; do
    case $pages in
        *-* )
            firstPage=${pages%%-*}
            lastPage=${pages##*-}
            ;;
        * )
            firstPage=$pages
            lastPage=$pages
            ;;
    esac
    echo "-dFirstPage=${firstPage} -dLastPage=${lastPage}"
done
```

Comment: nice alternate solution! Good use of ${pages%%-*}. But why are people afraid of case statments? You can eliminate all the extra processes with `case $pages in *-* ) .... ;; * ) firstPage=$pages ; lastPage=$pages ;; esac` . Also, I don't think you need "backtic echo, just `firstPage=${pages%%-*}; ...` Good luck to all.

Comment: `while IFS=, read -r pages; do ... done <(echo "$vars")` (in other words, that's not a proper use of `for`). No need for `[[ -n $(echo | grep) ]]` - you could do `if echo | grep -qs` (or redirect stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`) directly without brackets. Plus, what shellter said.

Answer (score 1):

Could you pass the value of `p` as a input to awk? In this case, I would do it this way:

```
$ echo 1,3,8,25-27,4-16 | awk -F- -v RS=, '{printf "-dFirstPage=%s -dLastPage=%s\n", $1, $2?$2:$1}'
-dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1
-dFirstPage=3 -dLastPage=3
-dFirstPage=8 -dLastPage=8
-dFirstPage=25 -dLastPage=27
-dFirstPage=4 -dLastPage=16
```

How this works:

- I define that comma will be the record separator (`-v RS=,`) and hyphen will be the field separator (`-F-`). So, the input

  ```
  1,3,8,25-27,4-16
  ```

  will be roughly equivalent to

  ```
  1
  3
  8
  25 27
  4 16
  ```
- Then, I use [`printf`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_32.html#SEC35):

  ```
  '{printf "-dFirstPage=%s -dLastPage=%s\n", $1, $2?$2:$1}'
  ```

  The first parameter is the first column. In the second parameter, I ask if the second column `$2` exists; if so, then the value of the parameter is `$2`; if no, the value is the first column `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

You were ***very*** close:

```
awk -v p=1,3,8,25-27,4-16 'BEGIN {split(p,t,",");for (i in t) if(t[i] ~ /-/) {split(t[i],t1,"-"); print "-dFirstPage=" t1[1] ,"-dFirstPage=" t1[2]} else {print "-dFirstPage=" t[i] ,"-dFirstPage=" t[i]}}' >outfile
```

- Use a `BEGIN` clause
- Change "ELSE" to `else`
- Move the curly brace from before the first `print` to before the `split` and place a semicolon where it was